# Please check my Regex to match color text

Tags: c#, regex

I Need to make some regex matching to color some text in richtextbox.

I already made a code but i have a problem whit performance , when I write inside that richtextbox the text show so slow not like normal richetextboxs especially when the text gets to long

I have tried to set each regex in a Separate Thread and nothing happens then made this one but same result

Here is my code:

```
public void  ColorAllQuery()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { 
            TextRange range = new TextRange(Richtext.Document.ContentStart, Richtext.Document.ContentEnd);
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));

            Regex FunctionsR = new Regex(Functions, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex Variables = new Regex(Variables, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex Tables = new Regex("(" + TablesNames + ")", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex Columns = new Regex("(" + ColumnsNames + ")", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex Qutation = new Regex(@"'.*?'|n'.*?'|"".*?""|n"".*?""", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex Comment = new Regex(@"(--.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            List<TextPointer> pointer = new List<TextPointer>() ;
            List<Match> matchs = new List<Match>();
            List<Brush> color = new List<Brush>();

            var start = Richtext.Document.ContentStart;

            while (start != null && start.CompareTo(Richtext.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
            {
                if (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
                {
                    var match = QuerysR.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
            var match2 = FunctionsR.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
            var match3 = Varubls.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
            var match4 = Tables.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
            var match5 = Columns.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
            var match6 = Quotation.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
            var match7 = Comment.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
            pointer.AddRange(new TextPointer[] { start, start, start, start, start, start, start });
            matchs.AddRange(new Match[] { match, match2, match3, match4, match5, match6, match7 });
            color.AddRange(new Brush[] { new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 120, 255)), Brushes.DeepPink, Brushes.LightGreen, Brushes.Orange, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Green });
        }
        start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }

    Thread OT = new Thread(() => ColorGatherdValues(pointer, matchs, color));
    OT.Start();
    }));
    });
    t.Start();
}

private void ColorGatherdValues(List<TextPointer> pointer, List<Match> matchs, List<Brush> color)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < pointer.Count; i++)
        {
            var textrange = new TextRange(pointer.ToArray()[i].GetPositionAtOffset(matchs.ToArray()[i].Index, LogicalDirection.Forward), pointer.ToArray()[i].GetPositionAtOffset(matchs.ToArray()[i].Index + matchs.ToArray()[i].Length, LogicalDirection.Backward));
            textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color.ToArray()[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. "

Comment: How big is this document?  Separate thread seems like waaay overkill.  If you are a beginner, maybe multi-threading should not be the first thing you try to figure out.  Start small.

Comment: 'this.Dispatcher.Invoke' invokes back to the GUI thread...which doesn't do any good if you want the work to not hamper the user.

Comment: Your Regex can be combined into one to reduce code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i have a problem whit performance

`this.Dispatcher.Invoke` invokes back to the GUI thread...which doesn't do any good if you want the work to not hamper the user.

You need to separate out the *what* the regex'es find, from the *how* to display it to the user. Running the regex'es in separate threads is a good strategy, but one should `invoke` the result back to the GUI after the work is done.

---

Make your processing easier, just do one thing in a thread for now. Once you get that working, then do the other operations.

Comment: ok but i will remove that invoke and make ColorGatherdValues() do the work but OldProgrammer said that my Thread is overkill and i know that so what should i do , remove thread and set the code inside a static void or what?

Comment: @Moa'adAl-a'athal By not doing the work in a separate thread, the work happens on the GUI thread. If the work takes time, the user will notice hesitation or a complete stop of the application. To avoid that, placing all extended work in a background thread is acceptable and common practice. That is what you must decide on whether it is taking up too much time on the GUI thread. IMHO I do all work on the background threads and keep the GUI thread clean except to push values to the controls by invoking.